# Why doesn't pow(sqrt(-1), 2) return -1?

Tags: c++, cmath

Instead, this operation returns -1.IND, since `sqrt(-1)` returns -1.IND. Does the domain error mentioned on the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/) that this sqrt returns for negative values not retain the info that this is actually *i*?

Is there some way to perform this operation for all negative numbers, so that it returns the correct value, i.e. `pow(sqrt(-36), 2)` will return -36?

Comment: By definition an even power of a real number is positive.

Comment: What you need is a complex number library.

Comment: If anything, it should except or return 0, (because the real part is 0 and 0^2 is 0).

Comment: The signature of `sqrt` is `double sqrt (double x);`. *`i`* is not a `double`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [std::complex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/) to achieve your goal, like this:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const std::complex<double> result = 
    std::pow(std::sqrt(std::complex<double>(-36,0)), 2);
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Real part = " << result.real() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
(-36,0)
Real part = -36
```

Note that [std::sqrt(std::complex)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt) is used here.

---

The reason behind the behaviour you encountered is the signatures of [sqrt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/), namely:

> double sqrt (double x);
>
> float sqrt (float x);
>
> long double sqrt (long double x);
>
> double sqrt (T x);           // additional overloads for integral types

which means that no matter which prototype will be used, you are getting nothing better than a `nan` (or a +-inf), since the return types can not support the imaginary part. That's why `std::complex` exists.

So, `sqrt(-1)` will be replaced by a `nan` probably, which can not be treated by `pow()`, so that -1 remains intact, because of the exponent. As a result the information is already lost after the call to `sqrt()` and `pow()` can do nothing about it.

Comment: I think cppreference has a better description of [std::sqrt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt).

Answer (score 6):

Because you're calling the function `double sqrt(double)`, and the `double` return value can only store real numbers, infinity (with sign), or NaN.  There is no representation for *i*.

If you want to store complex numbers, use [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Answer (score 4):

From [this `sqrt` reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt):

> If the argument is less than -0, FE_INVALID is raised and NaN is returned.

And then from [this `pow` reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)

> ... if any argument is NaN, NaN is returned

So you simply can't use `pow(sqrt(x), y)` for any real `x` that is negative.

Comment: Very nice explanation too, wonder why it has 0 upvotes. Will make that change!

Answer (score 3):

[`std::sqrt` is defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) to return implementation defined error on a domain error. In this case `(arg := -1) < -0` is a domain error.

[`std::pow` is also defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) to return an implementation defined error on a domain error.

So receiving `-1.Ind` is a plausible solution.

As Mystical pointed out you need a complex number library.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++14 you can use literal operators for complex:#include

```
<complex>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  using namespace std::literals::complex_literals;
  auto z = std::pow(std::sqrt(-36.0 + 0.0i), 2.0);
  std::cout << z << '\n';
}
```

Running this I get:

```
ed@bad-horse:~$ ./cpow 
(-36,4.40873e-15)
```

I know recent [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) and [clang](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1y_status.html) support this.  It looks like [VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx) does too.

This is actually a post-C++14 addition but it is still in a `std` namespace rather than `experimental`.